# How to filter running process in wmi_exporter query?

Tags: wmi, prometheus, grafana, wmi-query, wmi-service

> I am using the command **.\wmi_exporter.exe --collectors.enabled "process,cs" --collector.process.processes-where "Name LIKE 'chrome%' OR Name LIKE 'firefox%'"** to track both chrome and firefox browsers.
>
> But the metrics is collecting only the first running process whatever i am giving and not collecting the other one.
>
> In my metrics i can see only the 'chrome' and not able to see 'firefox' details.Kindly assist me where i am missing the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As of the current version of the wmi_exporter, you can specify multiple collectors using the whitelist.

For including processes that start with firefox or FIREFOX or chrome, you could supply the following flag:

> --collector.process.whitelist="firefox.+|FIREFOX.+|chrome.+"

Example taken from https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter/blob/master/docs/collector.process.md